# Convert to PKCS12 v1.0

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12

I am trying to convert a PEM file to PKCS12 by using openssl. Looks like the output PKCS12 is v3.0. I need to use it in EMC data domain appliance which only accepts PKCS12 1.0. Any way I can specify to output version 1.0 ?

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -in host.pem -inkey host.key -out host.p12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/pkcs12/p12_init.c#L72) I can assure you that OpenSSL supports only PKCS#12 version 3. So there is no way you can specify to output version 1.0 on command line. You would have to change the code.